# Ошибка в новом unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

Приветствую! В старой версии unity эта ошибка игнорировалась, в новом не дает с ней запускать игру:
`Step Offset` must be less or equal to `<scaled Height> + <scaled Radius> * 2`

> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Подскажите как поправить? Гугл не помог.
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Код покажете? старая версия - эта какая? Новая - эта какая?

Comment: в версии Unity 2017.3.0f3 (64-bit) ,

Comment: UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 17 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88

Comment: вот такую ерунду теперь выдает при сборке и не дает собрать

Comment: в версии 5.4.3f1 все собиралось корректно

Comment: А с какой целью обновлялись то?) собирали бы дальше на 5.4.3) Или там жесткий баг пофиксили, который вам мешал?

Comment: Не совсем решение, но если критично по времени (срочный релиз или еще чего): на сайте юнити доступны для скачивания старые версии установочников. Если скоро релиз - советую откатиться назад (разумеется, если обновлялись только ради "попробовать новую версию просто так").